# Changing/retrieving configuration settings on role start (Azure)

Tags: azure, configuration, configuration-files, azure-web-roles, app-startup

I'm trying to make a service to more easily configure configuration values on Azure applications. Right now, if I want to change a setting that it the same over 7 different environments, I have to change it in 7 different .cscfg files.

My thought is I can create a webservice, that the application will query for its configuration values. The webservice will look in a storage place, like Azure Tables, and return the correct configuration values.

I've been able to integrate this into a deployment script pretty easily (package the app, get the settings, change the cscfg file, deploy). The problem with that is every time you want to change a setting, you have to redeploy.

Finally the question - Is there a way I can retrieve the configuration settings after the application starts, on role start? It would of course need a base set of settings for the app to start. Retrieving the settings from the web service on application start would be good. Any way that I don't have to redeploy the application and that it will retrieve them automatically will work.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I've written a library because I had similar problems, it can read configuration values from a Table as well - https://github.com/aloneguid/config

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `.cscfg` for the minimum set (common to all environment) of configurable settings. The use your web services for rest of the configurations. And don't modify your .cscfg. Just have a settings provider that retrieves settings from web service (via polling or message signalling - pub/sub model). And have a `reinitialize settings` procedure in place for this settings provider and all the services/components that rely on configurable settings.

Comment: That's kind of what I was thinking of doing. Would I do it in a role start script? When it retrieves the values, where do I put them?